# Query join works in mysql workbench but not in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have created a db in mysql workbench with 4 tables, and exported/imported it in phpmyadmin.
Now i have a simple Join:

```
SELECT s.nomeser 
FROM `user` u , `service` s 
WHERE s.cat=u.category 
    AND category = "Admin";
```

but this query works in mysql workbench, but not in phpmyadmin. The db is the same.. any suggestions?

Comment: Query looks fine, did you select the database correctly in PMA?

Comment: PHPMyAdmin really likes it's single quotes.
Perhaps you should try:
select s.nomeser from `user` u , `service` s where s.cat=u.category and category = 'Admin';

Comment: i try but not works..

Comment: *Not works* means? What error do you get?

Comment: no errors but also no show me any results..in mysql workbench same db same data and show me the results.

Comment: Make sure it is really the same DB. I doubt it.

Comment: yes is the same.. i export it from mysql workbench and import in phpmyadmin..

Comment: You should remove part by part till you get any result... Maybe Admin is written wrong or with whitespace. One of the table user or service is empty?

Comment: Even if there's no error, have you got the `MySQL returned an empty result set` flash message ? As an aside, this query looks a bit strange. Isn't it the same as `SELECT nomeser FROM service WHERE cat = "Admin";` ?

Comment: yes is the same, i have the user table with a category attribute, and the table service with a cat attribute, i want to extract service for one user by category..

Comment: If category field is not ambiguous your query should work . check for record category = "Admin" in your tables.

Comment: the record is ok, i have table User with name,surname and category, with foreign key (fk_user_occup), table Occupation with categ, table Service with nameser and cat, and in last a table Occupation_Service with occupation_id and service_id with 2 foreign Key (fk_occup,fk_ser)

Comment: i try SELECT s.nomeser
FROM  `service` s
INNER JOIN  `user` u ON s.cat = u.category
but still nothing, no errors no results, but i have 1 record in user whit category set

Comment: i solved.. the problem was in the user table, the record category have a little error.

thanks to all!!

Comment: This little error in the user table should have produced the same problem when testing in Workbench...

Comment: yes but i don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

It maybe because of how your dot-walking as php admin might miss understand tableAlias.columnName as database.columnName

```
    Try this:
    SELECT s.nomeser 
    FROM yourDB.user u , yourDB.service s 
    WHERE s.cat=u.category 
        AND category = "Admin";

//where 'yourDb' is your database name
```

Answer (score -1):

you have not given the alias for the category in the where clause, this can be an issue,

try this query

```
select s.nomeser from `user` u , `service` s where s.cat=u.category and u.category = "Admin";
```

Comment: i try: select s.nomeser from `user` u , `service` s where s.cat=u.category and u.category = "Admin"; and select s.nomeser from `user` u , `service` s where s.cat=u.category and u.category = 'Admin'; but still no errors and no results..

Comment: if you are not getting any records then may be your database doesn't has records for that particular condition. or you can try building a demo of your workspace at http://sqlfiddle.com/ so we can test the issue properly.

Comment: Please check data with service table also, may be the records are not in that table.

Comment: i check, user table have one record quit name-surname-category, and service have 2 record with nameser-cat..

Comment: if i try select * from `user` s where s.category = 'admin' i have zero results but in the table i have one record with category = admin...why??

Comment: i solved.. the problem was in the user table, the record category have a little error.

thanks to all!!